# Swap Register Content without using a 3rd temp Register (ARM)

Tags: arm

I would like to swap the content of a 32 bit  R1 and R2 without using a 3rd temp register in ARM code.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure there is a nice way to say this, but the question shows no research effort at all. This is why it been downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell if this is a homework question, but you can use the [XOR swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm):

```
EOR r1, r1, r2
EOR r2, r2, r1
EOR r1, r1, r2
```

Comment: Thanks for help and link. Great.

Comment: I'm sure an instruction-set manual can answer that question now that the method is revealed.